# topological properties

Tags: general-topology

I have some questions about the initial and final topology, let $(f_i: X \rightarrow X_i)_{i \in I}$ be a source and let $(g_i: X_i \rightarrow X)_{i \in I}$ be a sink

1) If $I$ is countable, and if all $X_i$ are first countable respectively second countable, does that imply that the initial topology on X (with source $f_i$ (see above)) is first countable respectively second countable?

2) If all $X_i$ is separable respectively compact, locally compact, connected or path connected and we have the final topology on $X$ (see $g_i$ in introduction), can anyone give me an example that $X$ is not separable respectively compact, locally compact, connected or path connected?

3) If $I$ is countable, and let $(f_i: X \to X_i)_{i\in I}$ a source with the initial topology on $X$. If all $X_i$ are (pseudo)metrizable does that imply $X$ is also (pseudo)metrizable? I think not but I can't find a counterexample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proofs for 1) seem to be straightforward. Have you tried to prove it?

For 2) note that the topology on topological sum is final wrto inclusions of summands. This gives counterexaple to separability, compactness, connectedness and path connectedness. Do you assume being Hausdorff for locally compactness? If so then since there are non-Hausdorff quotients of locally compact Hausdorff spaces and quotient is another example of final topology, this gives a counterexample easily. If you don't assume that locally compact means Hausdorff that if I'm not wrong $\mathbb{R} / \mathbb{Q}$ in sense of quotient just contracting $\mathbb{Q}$ to a point is not locally compact in any sense (since any nbhd of $\mathbb{Q}$ contains infinite discrete closed subset).

For preserving of (pseudo)metrizability for initial topology: Any initial topology can be obtained as composition of following constructions: Taking products (in our example taking countable products), taking subspaces and taking initial topology generated by one quotient map. The first two cases preserves (pseudo)metrizability the third preserves pseudometrizability but not metrizability (e.g. quotient of two-point indiscrete space). So metrizability is not preserved but pseudometrizability is.

Comment: 1) I don't have an idea to prove it. I have troubles where in the proof I actually can use the fact that it is countable. 2) locally compactness: I don't assume it is Haussdorff. Can you give  an counterexample (as clear as possible) because I don't have an idea to do it. Thanks already

Comment: @Koen: So you have a proof without it? :-) Let's prove the second countability. You want to find a countable basis on $X$ and you have countable bases on $X_i$ and you should know how initial topology is formed. The initial topology uses open sets of all $X_i$s so if $I$ was too big then the topology could be also too big to have a countable basis.

Comment: 2) locally compactness: I don't assume it is Haussdorff. Can you give an counterexample (as clear as possible) because I don't have an idea to do it.+another question: If I is countable, and let $(f_i: X \rightarrow X_i)_{i \in I}$ a source with the initial topology on X. If all X_i are (pseudo)metrizable does that imply X is also (pseudo)metrizable? I think not but I can't find a counterexample. Thanks already

Comment: @Koen: Do you still have problems with 1) after my comment? If you don't assume locally compact means Hausdorff, you should define it in the question since there are more non-equivalent definitions of local compactness in non-Hausdorff case. I updated my answer for you new questions, but you should add the question about (pseudo)metrizability to the main question post.

Comment: 1) Can it be explained by this? The subbasis of the initial topology is countable because the basis of each X_i is countable and the union of countable collections is still countable. The basis is countable too because if you take the finite intersections, it remains countable. If this is true, I understand it + your answer about my thirth question (the question about the metrizability ) is clear

Comment: @Koen: Yes that is the argument. And the similar argument should work for first-countability.